# keepalived does not bind VIP

Tags: linux, debian, keepalived

I'm trying to get keepalived working between 2 debian jessie VMs.

I've defined the master machine to bind the VIP address to 172.128.28.6 as such:

```
global_defs {
        lvs_id tom_lvs
}

vrrp_instace tom_lvs {
        state MASTER
        interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 1
    priority 100
        authentication {
                auth_type PASS
                auth_pass 1234
        }

    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.28.128.6
    }

        virtual_server 172.28.128.6 3000 {
                delay_loop 10
                lb_algo wlc
                lb_kind DR
                protocol TCP
                persistence_timeout 1800
                sorry_server 172.28.128.3 3000
                real_server 172.28.128.4 3000 {
                        weight 1
                        HTTP_GET {
                                url {
                                        path /index.html
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

however, when I run `ip addr` I am not seeing a second IP attached to eth3:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f6:86:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef6:86bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:05:a5:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.128.4/24 brd 172.28.128.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe05:a5a1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I am obviously missing something here, but I've been at it for 2 days now and still didn't find it.

If at all relevant, the machines are running using vagrant and virtual-box, both defined to get their addresses from dhcp, and their IPs are 172.128.28.4 and 172.128.28.3 on the /24 subnet.

here is the output of `grep Keepalived /var/log/messages`:

```
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Configuration is using : 58175 Bytes
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1890]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Configuration is using : 12031 Bytes
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Feb 13 11:39:51 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1889]: Activating healthchecker for service [172.28.128.4]:3000
```

Comment: Please, post the log related to keepalived. It shows when keepalived is started and how mode is changed.

Comment: I've added the log mentions of keepalived in /var/log/messages. I couldn't find any other log. I hope that's what you were referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied / pasted your config file, I noticed a typo in your configuration. Other than this, all seems OK.

You need to fix the VRRP instance definition to read:

```
vrrp_instance tom_lvs {
```

You missed the second `n` letter in `vrrp_instance` keyword. After fixing your config and restart keepalived, you should see log lines similar to these:

```
Keepalived_vrrp[15607]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) Transition to MASTER STATE
Keepalived_vrrp[15607]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) Entering MASTER STATE
```